# XAMPP 1.8.2 - httpd.exe - Entry Point Not Found (xdebug)

Tags: php, xampp, xdebug

I download last version of xampp 1.8.2 for windows. Configure php.ini for using xDebug. When i restart my Apache i have a error:

> The procedure entry point zend_unmangle_property_name_ex could not be located in the dynamic link library php5ts.dll

I press ok and apache started without xdebug.

xdebug settings (worked  with xampp 1.8.1)

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
;xdebug.profiler_append = 0
;xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
;xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
```

Comment: looks like a version incompatibility for me. xdebug.dll seems to require a function which is not present in the php5ts.dll

Comment: what makes this strange is the fact that you are using an official release. I would contact the xampp support. (and post an answer here if you'll receive any news from them)

Comment: Thank you guys, you help me find this problem. I copy xdebug from 1.8.1 and apache starts without errors. The i go to xdebug of. site and dwonload all version for php 5.4. Then i checked all of them in my xampp and i find that version "PHP 5.4 VC9 TS (32 bit)" should be stored in this version of xampp (testing 2.2.1, 2.2.2 and 2.2.3 releases).